# AnyColumn option added as new column in Dojo enhanced grid view

Tags: dojo

I am working on dojo enhanced grid view. I am able to display the grid in UI. But AnyColumn option is added as new column.

Example:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated...

Here is the Code

```
var mygrid = new EnhancedGrid({
    id: "grid",
    store: gridStore, //Data store passed as input
    structure: gridStructure, //Column structure passed as input
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    initialWidth: width,
    canSort : true,
    plugins: {
        filter: {
          //Filter operation
          isServerSide: true,
          disabledConditions : {"anycolumn" : ["equal","less","lessEqual","larger","largerEqual","contains","startsWith","endsWith","equalTo","notContains","notEqualTo","notStartsWith","notEndsWith"]},
          setupFilterQuery: function(commands, request){
              if(commands.filter && commands.enable){
                  //filter operation
                }
              }
            }
}, dojo.byId("mydatagrid"));   


mygrid.startup();
```

Thanks,
Lishanth

Comment: Please post code and inline the image

Comment: Thanks Marged...Added the code, can you help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use EnhancedGrid, instead use either dgrid or gridx.

I think by default anycolumn is added to the dropdown. If you want to remove then, I would suggest to

1. Register for click event on the filter definition
2. Iterate through the drop-down and remove the first entry which is anyColumn

or you can also try something like

```
dojo.forEach(this.yourgrid.pluginMgr.getPlugin('filter').filterDefDialog._cboxes, function(dropdownbox) {

dropdownbox._colSelect.removeOption(dropdownbox.options[0]);
});
```

Updated answer is. I know this is not the elegant way of doing it but it works.

```
//reason why I'm showing the dialog is that _cboxes of the filter are empty initially.
    dijit.byId('grid').plugin('filter').filterDefDialog.showDialog();
dojo.forEach(dijit.byId('grid').pluginMgr.getPlugin('filter').filterDefDialog._cboxes, function(dropdownbox) {

          var theSelect = dropdownbox._colSelect;
          theSelect.removeOption(theSelect.options[0]);
          });

//Closing the dialog after removing Any Column
          dijit.byId('grid').plugin('filter').filterDefDialog.closeDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks manjunatha-muniyappa...Your code is not working for me. It is not removing the anycolumn.

Comment: @Lishanth, I want to see how you have used my previous suggestion (code). So please post the complete code. If possible post the jsfiddle link so that it is easy to test and debug

Comment: ...Thanks for you response...Here is the jsfiddle i have tried with you post above...http://jsfiddle.net/KDTcC/454/

Comment: @ Lishanth, I edited the answer to include the working code. Please test and let me know